# Why is this random password flagged saying it is too simplistic/systematic?

Tags: password, cracklib

How is the random string `M1uG*xgRCthKWwjIjWc*010iSthY9buc` being detected as too simplistic/systematic for a password according to [passwd](http://linux.die.net/man/1/passwd) and [cracklib-check](http://linux.die.net/man/8/cracklib-check)? Try it on your machine and see

```
echo "M1uG*xgRCthKWwjIjWc*010iSthY9buc" | cracklib-check
```

Note that this is not my password, but another randomly generated string from the same random password generator that produces the same result.

Comment: It says `M1uG*xgRCthKWwjIjWc*010iSthY9buc: OK`

Comment: Turns out only some versions detect this as simple.  See slm's answer for more info on this.

Comment: Why don't you instead use `/dev/urandom` to generate a password?

Comment: @devnull - not sure what you had in mind but added 2 methods to my A on how to generate passwords.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Since cracklib is open source, the answer can be found in the [source code](http://sourceforge.net/p/cracklib/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/cracklib/lib/fascist.c#l759).

"Too simplistic/systematic" means that there are too many characters that are preceded by one of their alphabetical neighbors. Hence "ab" or "ba" are considered bad, but "ac" or "ca" are OK since the b is omitted.

Before [this patch from 2010-03-02](http://sourceforge.net/p/cracklib/code/161/), it allows at most **four characters** that exhibit this trait. E.g., "bar12345" would fail, because the characters "a", "2", "3", "4" and "5" are alphabetical neighbors of the preceding characters.

slm found out in his answer that `M1uG*xgRCthKWwjIjWc*010iS` was OK, while `M1uG*xgRCthKWwjIjWc*010iSt` is not. Let's analyze. Here are the characters that cracklib-check thinks are indications of a systematic password:

```
M1uG*xgRCthKWwjIjWc*010iS
               ^^    ^^
```

which is below the max of four, but adding the t:

```
M1uG*xgRCthKWwjIjWc*010iSt
               ^^    ^^  ^
```

pushes it above the limit, since T follows S (it appears the test is case insensitive).

The patch changes the max limit so it depends on the total password length, to avoid false positives like this.

Comment: Shouldn't 010 count as 3 already? Great answer though.

Comment: Great answer and thanks for providing the exact source code diff. By the way, is there any reason why this file is called fascist.c?

Comment: @this.lau_ - I'm guessing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fascism

Comment: Somewhat funny to talk about "smaller" and "larger" in respect to characters, no? Well, though I know it's about ASCII values it may not be too obvious. -- So why not explain it a more simplistic way? *No character must be followed by its direct neighbor nor predecessor.* Hence neither "ab" nor "ba" is permitted, but "ac" or "ca" would since the b is omitted.

Comment: Is there a reason why it can't be one smaller or higher but it can be the same (`Ww`)?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel My guess is that identical characters are supposed to be covered by another check - namely the one that requires there to be at least 6 different characters.

Comment: @syntaxerror I agree and I did my best to rephrase it. The reason I used larger/smaller is not to confuse the position of the character in the password with the position of the character in the alphabet.

Comment: @waxwing this has improved by about 50% now. Good work. BTW it was just a suggestion, not to be understood as a downright criticism.

Answer (score 31):

#### On Fedora 19

When I run it I get OK. I'm on Fedora 19.

```
$ echo 'M1uG*xgRCthKWwjIjWc*010iSthY9buc' | cracklib-check
M1uG*xgRCthKWwjIjWc*010iSthY9buc: OK
```

Here's the version info:

```
$ rpm -qfi /usr/sbin/cracklib-check | grep -E "Version|Release"
Version     : 2.8.22
Release     : 3.fc19
```

**NOTE:** I'd try it with single quotes instead of double qutoes too since you're dealing with `*`'s they might be getting expanded in strange ways on you.

#### CentOS 5 & 6

Trying your example on CentOS 6 was fine, got an OK, but it did fail as you described on CentOS 5.9.

```
$ echo 'M1uG*xgRCthKWwjIjWc*010iSthY9buc' | cracklib-check
M1uG*xgRCthKWwjIjWc*010iSthY9buc: it is too simplistic/systematic
```

Version info:

```
$ rpm -qfi /usr/sbin/cracklib-check | grep -E "Version|Release"
Version     : 2.8.9                  
Release     : 3.3
```

#### A bug?

What you've stumbled into would seem to be a bug. If you take your string and run more and more of your string into `cracklib-check` you'll notice that when you get to the 26th character it starts to fail:

```
# 25    
$ cracklib-check <<<"M1uG*xgRCthKWwjIjWc*010iS"
M1uG*xgRCthKWwjIjWc*010iS: OK

# 26
$ cracklib-check <<<"M1uG*xgRCthKWwjIjWc*010iSt"
M1uG*xgRCthKWwjIjWc*010iSt: it is too simplistic/systematic
```

Digging deeper on this if I change the last character from a `t` to say `v` it continues to work.

```
$ cracklib-check <<<"M1uG*xgRCthKWwjIjWc*010iSvhY9b"
M1uG*xgRCthKWwjIjWc*010iSvhY9b: OK
```

So it would seem that in the version of `cracklib-check` is getting hung up on the substring `Sth`.

There's definitely something strange about chunks of the string you've provided. If I take the tail end piece and omit the front portion I can get this portion to fail as well.

```
$ cracklib-check <<<"jIjc*010Sth"
jIjc*010Sth: it is too simplistic/systematic
```

That same string causes issues on Fedora 19 & CentOS 6 too!

***UPDATE #1***

Based on @[waxwing's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121146/7453) very nice sleuthing, we now know that the heuristic used was getting tripped up if > 4 characters were too adjacent to each other. A [patch was introduced](http://sourceforge.net/p/cracklib/code/161/) that changed this heuristic so that the overall length of the password under consideration was taken into account to eliminate these false positives.

#### Conclusions?

Based on some of my limited testing it would appear that there are some strange heuristics at play here. Certain strings that would seemingly be fine are tripping it up.

If you're trying to codify this I would suggest wrapping the generation & evaluation of a password and then breaking out of the loop once a password has been generated that appeases `cracklib-check`.

Or at the very least I'd suggest upgrading to a newer version that includes the fixes that @maxwing mentions in his answer.

#### Password Gen Alternatives

*pwgen*

I'll also add that I usually use [`pwgen`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pwgen) to generate passwords. That might be helpful to you here as well.

```
$ pwgen -1cny 32
iWu0iPh8aena9raSoh{v6me)eh:eu6Ei
```

*urandom*

You can also use a little scripting magic with `tr`, `/dev/urandom`, and `fold` to get a extremely high quality random password.

```
$ tr -dc '[:graph:]' </dev/urandom | fold -w 32 | head -n 1
;>$7\`Hl$=zn}R.b3h/uf7mY54xp}zSF
```

The `fold` command can control the length. As an alternative you can do this too:

```
$ echo $(tr -dc '[:graph:]' </dev/urandom | head -c 32)
/_U>s[#_eLKAl(mrE@oo%X~/pcg$6-kr
```

Comment: I was running it on CentOS 5.5 with cracklib-2.8.9-3.1.src.rpm.  In either case though how can such a long random string be too simple?

Comment: @BeowulfNode42 - it isn't. Looks like you've found a bug, or at the very least a limitation of the implementation.

Comment: Strange.  Yet a string like `Tm7U:n=@*+4$*gf$6hOngEHJ;mnh$+R6` is perfectly OK on the same machine.

Comment: @BeowulfNode42 - seems to be an issue with the `Sth` substring.

Comment: @BeowulfNode42 - other portions of your string seem to be causing it issues too. `jIjc*010` is simplistic, `jIjc*01` is OK.

Comment: Double quotes *do* prevent glob expansion. Single quotes are still a better idea though, in case the string contains dollar signs, backticks, etc.

Comment: *"A patch was introduced..."* It should also be noted that the patch in question is by no means a recent one (unlike the way it may sound), but was already sent in back in 2010 :)