# PAM: Sequences in Linux Login Password Being Flagged Unexpectedly

Tags: security, password, pam

I am attempting to implement a password policy on Debian 8. I have the following in /etc/pam.d.common-passowrd:

```
password        requisite                       pam_cracklib.so difok=2 minlen=8 dcredit=0 ucredit=0 lcredit=0 ocredit=0 minclass=3 reject_username
password        requisite                       pam_echo.so blah blah
password        [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure use_authtok try_first_pass sha512
password        requisite                       pam_deny.so
password        required                        pam_permit.so
```

Upon setting a 15-character password that has three 5-character sequences in it, I am given the following error:

```
root@foo-host:~# ssh foo-user@localhost
Last login: Tue Aug 29 11:26:06 2017 from 127.0.0.1
WARNING: Your password has expired.
You must change your password now and login again!
blah blah
Changing password for foo-user.
(current) UNIX password:
New password:
BAD PASSWORD: it is too simplistic/systematic
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
Connection to localhost closed.
```

I have tried removing the "obscure" option to pam_unix and found no difference in behavior.

My pam_cracklib version is as follows:

```
root@foo-host:~# dpkg --list | grep -i crack
ii  cracklib-runtime               2.9.2-1                          amd64        runtime support for password checker library cracklib2
ii  libcrack2:amd64                2.9.2-1                          amd64        pro-active password checker library
ii  libpam-cracklib:amd64          1.1.8-3.1+deb8u2+b1              amd64        PAM module to enable cracklib support
```

Why is this occurring given that I did not specify maxsequence for pam_cracklib?

Comment: Where is the failure occurring? `pam_unix.so obscure` according to `pam_unix(8)` does some cracklib-type checks; to debug whether it is `pam_cracklib` or `pam_unix` add a `pam_echo blah blah` between them and see if that is called or not

Comment: thrig, I've updated my post to answer your question. I am surprised to see "blah blah" being echoed before I am even prompted for my *current* password!

Comment: Hmm, a password of `qW3$5qW3$5qW3$5` is ok on Debian 9. What version of cracklib does Debian 8 have given https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121087/why-is-this-random-password-flagged-saying-it-is-too-simplistic-systematic

Comment: I've now also added version information. I'm starting to think there are some checks that are "non-negotiable". For example, I came across a reference that said a minlen value of less than 6 will be ignored. Under no circumstances will pam_cracklib accept a password under 6 characters long. Perhaps something similar holds for sequences. Even though I am trying to get it to ignore sequences, very blatant, long sequences may be rejected regardless of option settings.